# Maps marker is not showing in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The map works fine but when I try to add a marker it doesn't work?

Here is my code so far:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    function initialize()
     {var mapProp = {

center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.975618,25.585858),
zoom:15,
panControl:true,
zoomControl:true,
mapTypeControl:true,
scaleControl:true,
streetViewControl:true,
overviewMapControl:true,
rotateControl:true,    
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("column2linksmap2"),mapProp);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  title:"Hello World!",
  visible: true
 });
  marker.setMap(map);


 }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
  position: (Give lat & long
   here),   title:"Hello World!",   visible: true  });  
   marker.setMap(map);
```

you might be missing to give latLng

Answer (score 0):

```
  position: latLng
```

Are you declaring latLng somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
function initialize() {
    var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: Latlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The problem is that you have not declared the **latlng**